# Select rows between an specified row to some row with particular condition

Tags: mysql

Hi
let's think we have a table (with 2 fields those are `version`,`compatible`) with data as follow :

```
+-------+------+  
| 0.1.1 | true |  
+-------+------+  
| 0.1.2 | false|  
+-------+------+  
| 0.1.3 | true |  
+-------+------+  
| 0.1.4 | true |  
+-------+------+  
| 0.1.5 | true |  
+-------+------+  
| 0.1.6 | false|  
+-------+------+  
| 0.1.7 | true |
```

now i want to select all rows where `version = '0.1.3'` from prior row that `compatible = false`to next row that `compatible = false`
result should be `0.1.2`, `0.1.3`, `0.1.4`, `0.1.5`
how can i do that ?

Comment: in your example you need to recive 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5 and 0.1.6 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT version, compatible
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE version >= '0.1.3'
        AND version < (SELECT version
                           FROM YourTable
                           WHERE version > '0.1.3'
                               AND compatible = 'false'
                           ORDER BY version
                           LIMIT 1)
    ORDER BY version
```

Comment: Great, so how if i want to select version between prior and next row that compatible is false. i mean 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5