# how to ignore a condition in where clause

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

SELECT field1 FROM table1
    WHERE field1 >= 4006 
      AND field1 < (
        SELECT field1 
        FROM table
        WHERE field1 > 4006
              AND field2 = false
        ORDER BY field1 
        LIMIT 1
    )

i want the second condition (`AND field1 <`) to be ignore if the inner select returned no record.

Related to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539645/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like (untested!):

```
SELECT field1 FROM table1
WHERE field1 >= 4006 
  AND (field1 < (
    SELECT field1 
    FROM table
    WHERE field1 > 4006
          AND field2 = false
    ORDER BY field1 
    LIMIT 1
    )
    OR
    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT field1 
    FROM table
    WHERE field1 > 4006
          AND field2 = false
    ORDER BY field1 
    )
)
```