# Conditions check in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I am trying to build a query and this is its `WHERE` clause so far:

```
WHERE ( s.subject_name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR
        c.city_name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR
        o.option_name LIKE '%$option%' OR
        d.district_id = $districtId OR
        c.city_id = $cityId
       )
```

My actual conditions are:

- `$keyword` should always hold a value. Other 3 may not.
- If only `$keyword` has a value, returned records should match
  `$keyword` in `subject_name` or `city_name`.
- If `$optional` have a value, then returned records should match `$keyword` and
  `$option`
- If `$districtId` has a value, then results should match the 3 variable values (`$keyword`, `$option`, `$districtId`)
- Finally if `$cityId` has a value along with the other 3, returned result should match all 4 variables' values.

These conditions come from my search page. `$keyword` is the value from a text box and a keyword is required to start searching. That's why I said it always has a value. Other 3 values come from select boxes that allows to select the items when they are needed.

I tried to make the query, its ok. But I am really confused with the `WHERE` clause. Above code is from my `WHERE` clause so far. But I can not get my desired result.

Comment: What is the desired result, and what do you geT?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540416/how-to-ignore-a-condition-in-where-clause?rq=1

Comment: output come if at least one of the five has to match

Comment: @PreetSangha I have checked that link before posting this. But I cant apply it to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this in pure SQL, this is what you need (or at least it should be close enough):

```
WHERE (
    ( s.subject_name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR c.city_name LIKE '%$keyword%' )
    AND ('$option' = '' OR (
        o.option_name LIKE '%$option%' AND (
            '$districtId' = '' OR (
                d.district_id = $districtId AND (
                    '$cityId' = '' OR c.city_id = $cityId
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

However, this is by far sub-optimal. Instead, you should check the contents of user input in PHP and run a different query depending on this input. You could also build the query dynamically:

```
$query = "SELECT ...";

$query .=
    " WHERE ( ( s.subject_name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR c.city_name LIKE %$keyword%' )";
if ( !empty($option) ) {
    $query .= " AND o.option_name LIKE '%$option%'";
    if ( !empty($districtId) ) {
        $query .= " AND d.district_id = $districtId";
            if ( !empty($cityId) ) {
                $query .= " AND c.city_id = $cityId";
            }
    }
}
$query .= ')';
```