# Ignore WHERE condition if record not found

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written the following script:

```
SELECT vil.account_id , 
       vil.imp_id, 
       vil.owner ,
       vil.start_date,  
       CASE  
         WHEN ac.status = 4  
         THEN status_date  
         ELSE NULL  
       END AS Live_date,
       cs.country_code  
  FROM ACCOUNT ac  
  INNER JOIN vu_imp_list vil  
     ON vil.account_id = ac.account_id  
  INNER JOIN entity e  
     ON ac.entity_id = e.entity_id  
  INNER JOIN country_specifics cs  
     ON e.country_id = cs.country_id  
WHERE ac.account_id IN
('000206789', '000207464', '000207696', '000207746')  
AND
(vil.start_date =  
(SELECT MIN(vils.start_date)
FROM vu_imp_list vils  
WHERE vil.account_id = vils.account_id)
```

This will return the oldest `imp_id` for each `account_id`. However, it will ignore those which do not have `imp_id`. As some `account_ids` do not have `imp_id` at the table `vu_imp_list`; `WHERE's second condition` will only extract only those records that have correspondent `start_date` and `imp_id`. In short, How to ignore this condition in case no corresponding record found in table `vu_imp_list`. I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540416/how-to-ignore-a-condition-in-where-clause) for MySQL related but seem something wrong with it as I keep getting error `missing SELECT keyword`

```
SELECT vil.account_id , 
       vil.imp_id, 
       vil.owner ,
       vil.start_date,  
       CASE  
         WHEN ac.status = 4  
         THEN status_date  
         ELSE NULL  
       END AS Live_date,
       cs.country_code  
  FROM ACCOUNT ac  
  INNER JOIN vu_imp_list vil  
     ON vil.account_id = ac.account_id  
  INNER JOIN entity e  
     ON ac.entity_id = e.entity_id  
  INNER JOIN country_specifics cs  
     ON e.country_id = cs.country_id  
WHERE ac.account_id IN
('000206789', '000207464', '000207696', '000207746')  
AND
((vil.start_date =  
(SELECT MIN(vils.start_date)
FROM vu_imp_list vils  
WHERE vil.account_id = vils.account_id))  
OR  
NOT EXISTS  
(vil.start_date = (SELECT MIN(vils.start_date)  
FROM obi.vu_implementation_list vils  
WHERE vil.ob10_account_id = vils.ob10_account_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, what you need is a `LEFT JOIN` when joining `ACCOUNT` table with `VU_IMP_LIST` and alter your condition in `WHERE` clause to check if `start_date` is either `NULL` (no corresponding record in `VU_IMP_LIST` found) `OR` it is equal to the value returned from the scalar subquery. Using `LEFT JOIN`, all records from `ACCOUNT` table will be returned, even if there is no corresponding record in the `VU_IMP_LIST` table:

```
SELECT vil.account_id , vil.imp_id, vil.owner , vil.start_date,
       CASE
         WHEN ac.status = 4 THEN status_date
         ELSE NULL
       END AS Live_date, cs.country_code
  FROM ACCOUNT ac
    LEFT JOIN vu_imp_list vil ON vil.account_id = ac.account_id
    INNER JOIN entity e ON ac.entity_id = e.entity_id
    INNER JOIN country_specifics cs ON e.country_id = cs.country_id
WHERE ac.account_id IN ('000206789', '000207464', '000207696', '000207746')
  AND (vil.start_date IS NULL
       OR vil.start_date = (SELECT MIN(vils.start_date)
                              FROM vu_imp_list vils
                            WHERE vil.account_id = vils.account_id))
;
```

You can read more about different types of joins here: [About SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Exactly, this is what I'm looking for. I just replaced `AND (vil.start_date IS NULL` with `AND (vil.imp_id IS NULL` as the older way will include the oldest `start_date` **and** `NULL` if there is any